# What is this battery connector called?

Tags: batteries, identification, connector

We received a product with this high-current battery connector, but don't know where to get the matching other half for it. Does anyone know what this connector is called?
[image]

Comment: What is the product? Can you ask the manufacturer or supplier?

Comment: "What is this battery connector called?" - Fancy!  =-D lol But seriously, what Colin, said, contact the manufacturer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That looks like an Amass connector, especially because it uses an "anti-spark" pin (black tipped pin), which is a feature exclusive to Amass. It's an extension of the "XT" type connector for high-current battery power in consumer products such as drones (such as the XT30, XT60, XT90).

https://china-amass.en.china.cn/

https://china-amass.en.alibaba.com/productgrouplist-813801759/MR_series.html?spm=a2700.icbuShop.88.26.448513d1gsJGbs

http://www.china-amass.com/product/index

**EDIT**: Found it!

AS150U

http://www.china-amass.com/product/contain/iW154529aUC817m6

[image]